# Ballot widget makes it hard to see whether you've seen the entire list of candidates

Tags: bug, design, election, responsive-design

The responsiveness of the Ballot widget on election pages is a bit unfortunate in some situations. Here is how it looks like in Firefox on a MacBook Pro 13" (with multiple tabs open). It's not clear you've reached the end of the candidate list (unless you know elections have at most 10 candidates) and you can't scroll down to see the bottom of the widget.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this situation is even related to responsive design. That's just a block that can't fit into page vertically, so everything you need - just a scroll the page. As in many other different situations.